# Armature pose different in modes. Yes, I have reset the positions

Tags: rigging

As stated in the title, my armature's position is changing slightly from one mode to another. I have reset the location, scale and rotation but i can't get the leg straight. Help would be greatly appreciated. I'm willing to provide a download link to the blender file if it's required.

[image: Armature and mesh in pose mode. Not desired poition]

[image: Armature and mesh in edit mode. Desired position]

Comment: you probably need to play with the Pole Angle in the lower leg IK constraint

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to see a "slight change" when all you provide is two pictures, one on top of the other.

I see you have two green bones, meaning they have constraints on them. May those be "Child of" or "Stretch to"constraints?
In which case, when you make a change in your rig, you need to go in each of these constraints and click either <kbd>set inverse</kbd> button for the "Child of", either <kbd>Reset</kbd> button for the "Stretch to".

If you don't wanna bother about going through each bone and clicking buttons everytime you change something, I have [some python scripts for you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122468/drivers-and-custom-properties-for-buttons/123107#123107).

EDIT: also check the IK's pole angles.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm sorry for being stupid but I'm afraid I simply don't understand what you mean. I'm new to rigging and asking for help, so I'm also sorry that the information i provided isn't enough.

Comment: Here: https://i.imgur.com/Yk636xC.png
There is two bones colored in green, meaning they have bone constraints. So select one of these, gon in the bone constraints tab (the icon is a little bone with a little chain link underneath). I guess you have a "Child Of" or a "Stretch To" constraint, just do what I said above, and to the same for every other bone having such constraint. If you can't understand all that, then maybe it's time for you to spend some time learning the rigging basics. It takes very few hours, and it will spare your from days of a headache.

Comment: The bone dosen't actually have a child of or stretch to constraint, it has a copy rotation constraint. There are no "set inverse" or "reset" buttons visible.

Comment: Ok. Then maybe it's your IK bone's pole angle. Check their IK constraints, try to play with their pole angles, it might just be that.

Comment: Changing the pole angle fixes it! Thank you so much for your help